# Groovy with extended choice parameter plugin

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, boon

I am trying to cook up a Groovy script to use with the Extended Choice Parameter plugin in Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin.

From the plugin page: the groovy script should return a JSON object that corresponds to the "options" object referred to in https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor. The example script does not work and throws error.

Could someone tell me how I can have Boon.fromJSON() return a JSON editor object? My intention is to have a pre-defined set values beings shown as parameters, each accepting a text against it (i.e, render as textbox).

Example (following the JSON editor way):

```
{
  "value1": "",
  "value2": "",
  "value3": ""
}
```

Even if it can be done without using Boon parser, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that `Boon.fromJSON()` takes a `String` as an argument.  The example at the plugin page isn't very clear to someone who may not know groovy very well:

```
def jsonEditorOptions = Boon.fromJSON(/{
    disable_edit_json: true,
    ...
}/);
```

The `/text/` syntax in groovy is the [Slashy String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_slashy_string).  Disregard this if you are already using this syntax but you haven't provided your code or error received.

Comment: I am using slashy string. Could you please provide me with a simple example of a creating a JsonEditorOptions object in Jenkins. I copied and pasted the large example that comes with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin, and it throws an error.

Comment: @naspras could you provide the error that is thrown?

Comment: Caught exception evaluating: it.getJSONEditorOptions() in /job/jobX. Reason: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.boon.Boon.fromJSON() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

Comment: Possible solutions: fromJson(java.lang.String), fromJson(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1367)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1353)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108) ...

Comment: I suspect there is a syntactic error in the way the editor options are created, and hence I requested for a simple example that would render an editor on Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the example on the wiki page.

Use Boon.fromJson instead of Boon.fromJSON.

Below is an example to render an editor on Jenkins page

```
import org.boon.Boon;
def jsonEditorOptions = Boon.fromJson(/{
        disable_edit_json: true,
        disable_properties: true,
        no_additional_properties: true,
        disable_collapse: true,
        disable_array_add: true,
        disable_array_delete: true,
        disable_array_reorder: true,
        theme: "bootstrap2",
        iconlib:"fontawesome4",
        schema: {
           "title": "Color Picker",
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
           "color": {
           "type": "string",
           "format": "color"
           }
         }
       },
       startval: {
         color :"red"
       }
}/);
```